# Mediaplayer is not working properly

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, while-loop, media-player

i am a beginner in android.
my code is

```
 MediaPlayer media;  
 media=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.beep);

 while(f<=3)
                {        
         media.start();                     
        f++;
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                    "Count="+f, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
}
```

in this code beep occurs only once.while loop is working but sound is played only once.while debugging sound occurred at `public void stop() throws IllegalStateException`  each time(looping) .But while running the application it plays sound only once.

Comment: Instead of mediaplayer to start() 3 times. Do media.setLooping(true). Android based on your condition you can stop the loop. Without media player to stop you are again staring the player. It will cause exception.

Comment: when using media.setLooping(true),it does not stop according to the condition.

Comment: you can use this. new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
    
    if(media!=null && media.isLooping())
     media.stop();
    
   }
  }, 3000);    // Please change the time according to the conditions.

Comment: where i can apply this?

Comment: you can place this code below media.start(). The call will come to this code after 3 seconds.

Comment: I posted a answer, Please refer that.

Answer (score 1):

```
MediaPlayer media;  
media=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.beep);
media.setLooping(true);
media.start();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{ 
@Override public void run() 
{ 
if(media!=null && media.isLooping()) 
media.stop(); 
}
 }, 3000);
```

If you have any query, Please let me know.